# Java ME and Device Manager system.properties

Tags: java-me

I use win7 and there is a problem with Java ME SDK 3.0 Device Manager. When I run my program on Netbeans IDE 7.0.1, error is detected.(Failed to connect to device 0!
Reason:
Emulator 0 terminated while waiting for it to register!)

I searched this problem and I found something.(javamesdk_installdir>\toolkit-lib\modules\bootstrap\conf\system.properties)
I need to change some settings but I can't do. When I save settings, problem with another program is occured.
"Please check whether if this file is opened in another program". I closed IDE and Device Manager. Which program does relate with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this site to [Customize Your J2ME Emulator](http://code-dojo.blogspot.com/2010/01/customize-your-j2me-emulator.html)